# spring modelandview redirect not working in jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am returing modelview attrbute form below controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView loginUser(@RequestParam(value = "userName") String userName,
            @RequestParam(value = "password") String password,
            ModelAndView model) {
     on success login

       return new ModelAndView("redirect:/another controller here");
     on failure login 

           return new ModelAndView("same page");
```

i have jquery ajax call which invokes this controller, when successful login i want to user to take another page, but my response comes to the same page instead of redirecting to another page.

help needed

EDIT - I am using URL based view resolver and Apache tiles for view rendering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your problem, the redirect will take place within the context of the AJAX call - so the JQuery AJAX code will follow the redirect and receive the response it gets back from `/another controller here`. This won't trigger a full page refresh but the response will be available by the JQuery AJAX code for rendering in the current page.

To change the whole page on successful login, you may be better to not use AJAX for this screen.

Alternatively, you could return some indicator to tell JQuery to redirect. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView loginUser(@RequestParam(value = "userName") String userName,
        @RequestParam(value = "password") String password,
        ModelAndView model) {

     on success login
       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("same page");
       modelAndView.addObject("redirectUrl", "/another controller here");
       return modelAndView;

     on failure login 
       return new ModelAndView("same page");
```

And then have some Javascript in `same page` that looks for the presence of `redirectUrl` and triggers a full page redirect if present.

```
var redirect = '${redirectUrl}';
if (redirect) {
    window.location.replace(redirect);
}
```

Comment: you saved my life, i was banging my head bro.thanks a lot it worked .

Comment: you mentioned not to use Ajax call for this, can you please explain me what it issue using Ajax for login, and if you have better approach that will be great thanks

Comment: If you want to remain on the same page after you've signed in, then that would be a good case for using AJAX. For example, you may have some kind of login widget embedded in the page sidebar or banner which allows the user to sign in whilst staying on the same page. If however you have a dedicated login screen which sends you to a completely different page after successful login, then it'd be simpler and more conventional to use a regular browser form post. It's less complex - and probably slightly more natural from a user's point of view.

Comment: yes i do have separate login page which will take to different page after successful login, but in case of error for instance:- invalid username or pwd, i feel ajax is better choice since i dont want to refresh page. is it possible do form submit in case of ajax successful login, when i get response form controller?.

Comment: Normally where you have a single login page, a full form post, rather than AJAX, would be more conventional. When a login error occurs, an Errors object would be populated (either in a controller or by a framework like Spring Security) and then the request would be forwarded back to the login page and the errors would be rendered from the Errors object. There's nothing stopping you from using AJAX but it would really just overcomplicate what is otherwise a fairly conventional interaction for this type of page. If you're concerned about performance, I doubt you'll notice any difference.